# What is the /\\/ Object in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, object, console

When i type */\\/* (slash, backslash, backslash, slash) into any javascript console in any browser, it just returns /\\/. I assume, this is an object, but what is it there for?
Thank you for answers.

Comment: It's a [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) literal.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Answer (score -1):

It is a [literal](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-primary-expression-regular-expression-literals) for a [`RegExp`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-regexp-regular-expression-objects) that matches a backslash.